# HTML <video> Playback on Mobile Devices not working

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

While trying to play a video back on mobile I am not able to play it. I don't currently have a CDN so I can't upload it onto the CDN. Does Anyone know why I cannot play the video?

```
<a href="#" class="play" onclick="toggle();"><img src="play.png" alt="">Watch </a>
<div class="trailer">
        <video src="JH/Episode1/E01[1080p].mkv" controls="true"></video>

        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's likely that your mobile device either doesn't support MKV or doesn't support the codecs used within.  You could try simply renaming it to `.webm`.  (WebM and MKV share the exact same file structure.  The only substantive difference is that WebM is restricted in the codecs it uses.  If the codecs you're using are compatible, it might "just work" by chance.)  If that doesn't work, you'll have to use a tool like FFmpeg to transcode the video to a supported codec and container.

Comment: @Brad I just tried changing the container and codec and still not working on mobile devices. Any other advice?

Comment: What did you change it to? H.264 and AAC in MP4 is always a good choice.

Comment: Convert file to MP4 for best compatibility. Not obvious what _"mobile devices"_ you mean but be aware that not all OS or brands will support MKV. With Android you might be lucky but I think iOS only wants MPEG video (3GP, MOV, MP4).

Answer (score 0):

If you have OBS, you can use 'Remux recordings' to convert your .mkv a mp4.

[image]